# How to make a background use sprite image

Tags: html, css, background, css-sprites

I have a big div that covers all the screen, I use a background image on that div, but now, I want to make that image part of a sprite image, so I have less HTTP requests. The problem is that, I don't know how to make the div use just a piece of the sprite and not to show the entire image, example:

```
div{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(52, 52, 52, .5);
    position: fixed;
    background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/S7v0Xyn.png');
}
```

[Jsfiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/NMtX7/)

I just need to use the little grid you can barely see on the sprite image, not the entire image, and I also want the grid to repeat all over the div.

Comment: You must set the width, height and position of the image you want to use. [Example1](http://jsfiddle.net/NMtX7/2/), [Example2](http://jsfiddle.net/NMtX7/3/)

Comment: @Vucko Yes, I know, but how do I do it in this case.

Comment: I updated examples in the comment.

Comment: @Vucko The thing is that I use width and Height to set the div size itself, I need to set the background size.

Comment: [Read this](http://www.phpied.com/background-repeat-and-css-sprites/).

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

1. you set the image to a position where you can not see it with the class icon
2. later you set a seccond class .icon.facebook with the right position and the sice from the sprite you like to show

http://jsfiddle.net/NMtX7/5/

```
 <span class="icon facebook"></span>
 <span class="icon twitter"></span>


.icon {
    background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/S7v0Xyn.png');
    background-position:3000px 3000px;
}
.icon.facebook {
    border:2px solid green; /* you don't need this*/
    margin:20px;            /* you don't need this*/
    background-position:0px 0px;
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
    display:inline-block;

}
.icon.twitter {
     border:2px solid orange;
    background-position:-32px 0px;
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: @Andres ooh, do you mean you want to repeat the grid all over the screen? if so you can not use sprites. sprites don't work with repeated imgs. all repeated imgs have to be set as single img!

Answer (score 0):

Caramba beat me to it, so I am including a JSFiddle purely to show another use for it.

[SAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/NMtX7/6/)

HTML:

```
<ul id="nav">
    <li><a class="facebook" href="#"></a>Facebook</li>
    <li><a class="twitter" href="#"></a>Twitter</li>
    <li><a class="browsers" href="#"></a>Browsers</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
#nav {
    width: 200px;
}
#nav li {
    list-style-type: none;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: "Courier", sans-serif;
    padding: 10px;
}
#nav li a {
    background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/S7v0Xyn.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    display: block;
}
#nav li a.facebook {
    background-position: 0px 0px;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
}
#nav li a.twitter {
    background-position: -33px 0px;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
}
#nav li a.browsers {
    background-position: 0px -40px;
    width: 65px;
    height: 17px;
}
```

Comment: No man, the idea is to use the little grid you can barely see under the browsers icons as the background for a div that covers the whole screen with width=100% and height=100%. Check out my example. http://jsfiddle.net/NMtX7/